# Create a constant for "this" in Lightning helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

Is there any possibility to create a constant for "this" in Lightning helper?
I have tried the following syntaxis:

```
self : this,

initializeInputs : function(component, webLeadData) {}
```

But I receive the following error message:

> Error:(1, 1) c.ddcm_quote:
>   org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Invalid literal value [6, 12]: 'this'

Comment: you can use that in helper method not outside it.

Comment: In each function of this helper I do the following: let self = this, and use this "self" where it is needed. I want to declare "self" one time outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot do that is because that `this` will directly point to window. This is not allowed in lightning because of `locker service`.

**Further Explanation:**

`helper` or `controller` in lightning component are actually a part of closure function which would render like below in client machine:

```
(function () {
        const { $A } = window;

        return {
            "meta": {
                "name": "c$MyAuraComponent",
                "extends": "markup://aura:component"
            },
            "controller": {
                "doInit": function (component, event, helper) {

                }
            },
            "helper": {
                "helperMethod": function () {

                },
                "helperMethod2": function () {

                }
            }
        };

    }())
```

So here when you add variable pointing to `this` in `helper`, it will directly refer to `window`. Hence it will not even compile.

**Note:** However, when you define `this` inside helper function, its not a problem as function is scoped and lightning framework will take care of referring to helper functions.